# Android 2.3 Notification custom view with ToggleButton

Tags: android, notifications

I'm programming Android 2.3 (API 10) application.

I've managed to create a custom view to my Notification object with ImageView and TextView.

I want to add to my Notification a ToggleButton (Kind of like the toggle button exists in the phone call options in the notification when you're in a middle of a phone call with "Speaker" and "Mute" Toggle buttons).

Every time i'm trying to do so - my application's crash with the following error:

```
08-15 00:15:55.370: E/AndroidRuntime(17000): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-15 00:15:55.370: E/AndroidRuntime(17000): android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package com.coapps.pico: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification(package=com.coapps.pico id=0 tag=null notification=Notification(vibrate=null,sound=null,defaults=0x0,flags=0x0))
08-15 00:15:55.370: E/AndroidRuntime(17000):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1048)
08-15 00:15:55.370: E/AndroidRuntime(17000):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-15 00:15:55.370: E/AndroidRuntime(17000):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-15 00:15:55.370: E/AndroidRuntime(17000):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
08-15 00:15:55.370: E/AndroidRuntime(17000):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-15 00:15:55.370: E/AndroidRuntime(17000):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-15 00:15:55.370: E/AndroidRuntime(17000):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
08-15 00:15:55.370: E/AndroidRuntime(17000):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
08-15 00:15:55.370: E/AndroidRuntime(17000):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any idea how can i make it work ?

Comment: as far as I know this feature didn't exist in android 2.3, it's a newer 4.1 feature.

Comment: which feature ? i've created my own custom XML with notification and works with TextView and ImageView but not with ToggleButton

Comment: interactive notifications.

Comment: yeah that for onclick listeners on buttons and stuff.. but i only want to show it for beginning.. it must be possible since the phone calling app has toggle buttons in its notification view

Answer (score 0):

Usually bad notification error occurs during notification building process;
when you try to include views which are not ought to be used in notification(Here is the reference to the video where it is mentioned "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ToUR9i4Smfw").
Conclusion:
Remove ToggleButton from custom layout;
try to use ImageButton instead.